# What is the MySQL equivalent of PSQLException

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am trying to move my database and web app from PostgreSQL to MySQL, the application is using play 2.3.0.

I made the app work with MySQL but I haven't yet made the error management, i'll need your help there:

the original code uses PSQLException like this:

```
import org.postgresql.util.PSQLException

try {
      SQL("DELETE FROM Lab WHERE id = {id}")
        .on("id" -> lab.id)
        .executeUpdate()
      true
    } catch {
      case e: PSQLException
        if e.getMessage.contains("update or delete on table \"lab\" violates foreign key constraint \"conference_organizedby_fkey\" on table \"conference\"") |
           e.getMessage.contains("update or delete on table \"lab\" violates foreign key constraint \"appuser_lab_fkey\" on table \"appuser\"")
        => Logger.warn(e.getServerErrorMessage.getMessage); false
    }
```

I don't find the MySQL error handler that is the best for this type of error.

What do you think I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just catch [`SQLException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html), of which `PSQLException` is an implementation, and stick to its methods - namely `getMessage()`

Unless you *really* need the extra info `PSQLException` provides, it is better not to know the actual class of the exception, because then you are invisibly binding your handler to the JDBC connection path.